# SSLException [org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException https://chec.. Connection reset; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException ]

Tags: sslexception

I am trying to invoke HTTPS end point using rest template and I am getting SSLException as per below.
I have also included code to read truststore info from GCP bucket and set with System and it executing all steps nicely but still can see SSLException during invoke.

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/public/act/check/GetPostingStatus: Connection reset; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset at

[image]

Comment: Why would you post same thing more than once? That definitely won't help you getting answers faster, most likely the exact opposite. Also, you might want to consider tagging more relevant things.

Answer (score 0):

**Connection reset**: This typically occurs when the remote server abruptly closes the connection while your application is trying to communicate with it. This can happen for various reasons, including network issues, server overload, or security configurations.

- Check that the remote server you are trying to connect to is up and running. You can test the server's availability by accessing it via a web browser or using tools like ***curl*** or ***telnet***.
- If you are using SSL/TLS for secure communication, verify that your SSL/TLS **certificates** and configurations are set up correctly on **BOTH** the **client** and **server** sides (`eg. server_cert.jks and client_cert.jks` :: you probably forgot to include *client-certificates*). Ensure that the server's certificate is valid and trusted by the client, and client's certificate is valid and trusted by the server!

Useful links:

- [Authentication in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security)
- [Mutual Authentication](https://refactorizando.com/en/mutual-tls-communication-in-spring-boot/)
- [Set Up Mutual TLS SSL](https://dzone.com/articles/hakky54mutual-tls-1)